# error in solidity with a payable function

Tags: solidity

I'm new to Solidity and i have this function to send value from the user account to the contract. It increments the balance of the user and that info is stored in a mapping.

```
function sendMoney() public payable {
    payable(address(this)).transfer(msg.value);
    balance_received[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}
```

It compiles and i can deploy but when calling the function i get this message:

"The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."

I have funds in the user account and i state in the function that it's payable. What am I missing?

Thanks